# call a vendor function in custom module

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides, phtml

I'm trying to create a custom module which will have GoogleSheet Import functionality. So I want to call `varienImport.postToFrame()` this function works when we click on **Check Data** option in existing Import section.

This is js function which exist in **before.phtml** file.

So How can I use this function in my custom module

Answer (score 0):

You can include the template in your page and then call the function:

Add this to the layout file corresponding to your admin page:

```
<block class="Magento\ImportExport\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit\Before" template="Magento_ImportExport::import/form/before.phtml" name="import.form.before" as="form_before"/>
```

Then you can call `varienImport.postToFrame()` at the click of a button from your own template or any other way you need it.